# Programmatic Saving of SSRS Reports Creating Damaged PDFs

Tags: sql-server, vba, pdf, reporting-services, ssis

I have created an SSIS package that is supposed to run an SSRS report from the Report Server and generate PDF's accordingly. Currently, there are two main issues:

1. The PDF files are all 52 KB in size (they should vary from 250-300 KB)
2. The PDF files that are generated cannot be opened because they are "either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged."

Below is my VB script task that does the actual work. I have verified that I have the proper connections established in my Connection Manager, that the URL I am using to reference the SSRS report is correct, and the SSRS report itself doesn't have any errors. Any thoughts?

```
Imports System    
Imports System.Data    
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum


    Public Sub Main()
        Dim httpConn As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("ReportServer")
        Dim clientConn As HttpClientConnection = New HttpClientConnection(httpConn.AcquireConnection(Nothing))
        Dim ReportFilename As String = "path\" & Dts.Variables("User::Dealers").Value & ".pdf"
        clientConn.ServerURL = "http://url"
        clientConn.DownloadFile(ReportFilename, True)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Comment: maybe you could call the report server functionality for rendering PDF: `http://localhost:8080/reportserver?/MyReports/Report1&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF`

Comment: Open the results with your favorite text editor. What is written inside?

Comment: I currently have the render command on the end of my URL but when i add the &rs:Format=PDF portion, the size of the generated PDFs drops to 0 KB :/

Comment: have a look a this c# example, this works perfect in my case: http://forums.asp.net/t/1549431.aspx?Code+to+render+the+report+in+PDF+format+using+C+in+SSRS+2008

Comment: It looks like html for the PDF's format in Notepad++

Comment: Resolved! It turns out you have to have your parameter values set in your url BEFORE the render/format commands. Thanks for all your help!